# What will be the conditional probability for given case?

Tags: probability

I have 20 data entries of 1's and 0's. Count of 1's is Probability A and Count of B is probability B. How can I calculate conditional probability of $1$ given $0$. I can't figure out what will be my joint probability?

data = [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
Prob A = 4
Prob B = 20 - 4 = 16

Comment: Conditional probability of $1$? Conditioned on what exactly?

Comment: I edited my question. Thank you for your response

Comment: Hint: What is the intersection of A and B?

Comment: @Did That's what I don't know. I have two cases. **Case 1:** i just have data and I have to calculate conditional Prob. **Case 2: ** 1 can occur with 0.75 in the data and than I have to calculate conditional prob of 1 given 0 again?

Comment: Since you very quickly accepted an answer, I guess there is not much to discuss anymore, so let me simply mention that the answer is most probably 0, not one of the elaborate values mentioned below.

Comment: @Did, I would appreciate your help. I am still working on this problem

Comment: @Mano2733 You should not click the green checkmark you are fully satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To begin with, **Probability always lies between 0 and 1; defined as (favourable 
 outcomes)/(total outcomes)**. In your case, event A has occured 4 out of 20 times. So,
 **P(A)=4/20 i.e. 0.2

          Similarly, P(B)= 1-P(A) = 0.8**

You have asked for 1 given 0. Assume an event where you are selecting a random
 number from given set. An outcome can be either 1 or 0. For 1 given 0, you need to find
 probability that 1 occurs given that 0 has already occured. So your conditional
 probability becomes P(A/B).
          So, in the first draw, you must get a 0. P(getting 0)= 16/20= 0.8

**Now that you drew a 0 out of your set consisting of 20 elements, you have 19 elements left** **(assuming a drawn 0 is not replaced)**-
4 1's and 15 0's.
Now, you want to draw a 1. There are 4 1's among 19 elements. So,
 P(drawing 1)= 4/19 = 0.2105
 Final probability will be product of both the probabilities. **0.8*0.2105= 0.1684**

**Alternately, if it is assumed that there are still 20 elements in your set after drawing out a 0,**
P(drawing a 1) will be 4/20= 0.2
So, final probability will be **0.8*0.2= 0.16**

Comment: I did not understand "For 1 given 0, you need to find
probability that 0 occurs given that 1 has already occured". Why do I need this? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. it will be 'For 1 given 0, you need to find
probability that 1 occurs given that 0 has already occured.'

Comment: it is because  u r dealing wid an event wen 0 has already occured and now 1 has to appear. This is what 1 given 0 means.

Comment: Thank you, I understood that now. What if I don't get 0 in first draw but 1?

Comment: u have to find prob of getting 0 in first draw. finding prob doesn't mean u will surely draw a 0

Comment: don't think about what comes, think what can come or what has greater prob to come

Comment: prob of getting 0 in first draw is 16/20 and prob of getting 1 in first draw is 4/20 in given data.

Comment: yes, but u have to get 1 in second draw

Comment: that can be 4/19 or 4/20 depending upon if replacement is allowed

Comment: The final prob **0.1684** means that at 21 location of data 1 can occur with this much probability than 0.

Comment: wat do u mean by 21 location?

Comment: dis is prob of getting 1 on 2nd draw wen u got 0 on 1st

Comment: I mean after given data is the 21th draw, this data has 20 draw entries.

Comment: entries may change from 20 to 19 after 1st draw not 21

Comment: Basically I need to get the probability of 1 at 21th draw if I have given data of 20 draws already. I have to use conditional probability to solve this problem. All I understood is I have to count 1's  and 0's as probability A and B. and Probability of 1 at 21th draw as probability of 1 given 0 and could not solve it.

Comment: replacement is not allowed in this problem.

Comment: dis completely changes ur question

Comment: do u want 1 at 21st?

Comment: we cant find it directly actually

Comment: coz theres no sample space to select 1 from. u simply cant solve dis.

Comment: wats the answer given?

Comment: So I was at wrong direction in solving the given problem. I don't have answer for this problem.

Comment: just throw that 21st position concept. u will draw from given set, not for it.

Comment: u get 0.1684 if no replacement

Comment: I am so sorry. I ask a wrong question for my problem. Thank you so much for your help. I have to look for other method than conditional probability.

Comment: its ok. just be through wid all concepts be4 trying to apply them in problems.

Comment: So 0.1684 is the probability of 1 if this data is given. if i throw away 21th draw concept?

Comment: yes, if no replacement. otherwise 0.16

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Idea. Though i was wrong from start. I will mark your comment as answer. Thank you again.

Comment: Then I am going with this... Thank you